# Nested for loop PHP table like result

Tags: php, loops, nested

How can I print this output using a FOR - NESTED loop using PHP?

It's not really helpful for me getting ready code, but, I've been trying for a couple of hours now. I want to understand how to reach this result using a nested for loop.

Result should be like this.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of the outer loop as the row numbers and the inner loop as the column values.

The trick is to start the inner loop (the column values) with the value of the outer loop (the row numbers) to achieve the offset for each row. Then take the inner loop value mod edge size to get the correct number.

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {

    // start with current value of $x
    for ($y = $x; $y < $x + 10; $y++) {

        // use mod to calculate the correct value
        echo $y % 10 . ' ';
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ha, beat me by 37 seconds :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh, sorry, it had been a few minutes, so I figured you'd moved on already